# Is it allowed to set form-action to include *.localhost:3000 in Content Security Policy?

Tags: content-security-policy

I'm getting this error:

```
Refused to send form data to 'http://example-subdomain.localhost:3000/'
because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive:
"form-action 'self' *.example.co *.localhost:3000".
```

So simply I would like to be redirected from staging server (`example-staging.com`) to local machine (`http://example-subdomain.localhost:3000/`). It works perfectly when I'm using `localhost:4000` for my backend app, so redirect from `localhost:4000` to `http://example-subdomain.localhost:3000/`.

So to just clarify what is what:

`http://example-subdomain.localhost:3000/` - frontend app on local machine

`example-staging.com` - staging server, backend api

`localhost:4000` - backend app on local machine

Answer (score 0):

I tested this thing only in Chrome. It works fine in Firefox. Looks like a bug in Chrome browser. I'm going to report it.